# In Ruby on Rails, what is good way for a site specific config / yaml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If a website is to be "cloned" as a different website, so that only the title, header, banner logo, and the products of the site are different, it probably will be good to move all the site-specific data to a config or yaml file.

(probably better if not using `environment.rb` so that the data is separate from other data, to keep it more self-contained, and easier for Program Management to edit the data)

In Rails 3, what is a good method to do this?  I think the data probably will be mostly text, plus some data such as what product data to fetch from the main DB.  The color theme / sprite offsets probably will still be best to keep in a separate `.sass` file.

Comment: Are you intending to run two different sites from the same app at the same time, two different skins, or are you talking about forking one app into two different, independent sites but just making it easier to manage?

Comment: it is 2 apps for 2 sites, or 3 apps for 3 sites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doing the following
Created a my_config.yaml under config folder with development, test and production settings.
Then used a script under initializers to load those settings

Contents of config/my_config.yaml

```
# This file contains all the Application Configuration
# config/my_config.yml

development:
  greet: Hello Developer
test:
  greet: Hello Tester    
production:
  greet: Hello World
```

Contents of config/initializers/load_config.rb

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/my_config.yml")[RAILS_ENV]
```

And now I can use APP_CONFIG['greet'] in my app

If you common setting across all environment then you can do some thing like the following

Contents of config/my_setting.yaml

```
page_title: Hello World
page_header: This is a test
```

Contents of config/initializers/load_settings.rb

```
APP_SETTING = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/my_setting.yml")
```

Comment: actually, what if we would like all values to be the same for dev, prod, and test?  Because for example, the page header, would be the same for any environment

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Since `RAILS_ROOT` is deprecated, the above script should deploy `Rails.root.to_s`